# How to create a "java.lang.Class" object from a .java file in java

Tags: java, reflection, junit, compilation

How can I instantiate an object of the class `java.lang.Class` from a given .java file?

I want to create an application to automatically generate JUnit tests. For that I would need "Method" objects and for "Method" objects I need to have a "Class" object.

Comment: I want to create an application to automatically generate JUnit tests. For that I would need "Method" objects and for "Method" objects I need to have a "Class" object.

Comment: @NiceBooks You should probably be a little more specific still. What exactly will be the input to your application? The source code you want to generate tests for?

Comment: @millimose For the moment, I am planning to do it from a .java/.class file, but later I want to do it for code (text) as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

java 6 onwards has an api for the compiler: http://www.javabeat.net/2007/04/the-java-6-0-compiler-api/

the link above includes an example.

here's another example - http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/JavaCompilertoolshowyoucancompileaJavasourcefrominsideaJavaprogram.htm

to load the file once compiled you use a classloader.  there's an example at http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html and another at http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-1996/jw-10-indepth.html

you'd think there would be a library to simplify all this.  i can't find one, but am still looking.

meanwhile, here's a really nice article from ibm that compiles a function and plots it - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jcomp/index.html

**found one** http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home - this is a library that simplifies the process.  i would recommend configuring it to use the javax.tools API (see last sentence in the "what is Janino" paragraph).

sorry for the google snark earlier.

---

it just struck me that maybe you just want a class object.

if you have a class called MyClass then the associated class is `Myclass.class`.  that's probably obvious, but perhaps that's all you need.

and if you have the class name in a string you can use this method - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. You can't instantiate an object from a file or dynamically changeable code. This is not supported by Java.

Comment: why can't you use a classloader to load it once compiled?  i have to wash the pots from dinner, but when i'm done i'll google that too.

Comment: @algorian To expand on andrew's last comment, use an [`URLClassLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html) for classes written to the local file-system, or a custom class-loader for gaining resources from ..byte arrays or whatever.

Comment: This is like having JavaScript Eval() function in Java. But there is no Eval in Java and there can't be too. Because when you use for example Eval('alert()') you are telling JavaScript to run the code 'alert()' (without quotos). But in Java, there is no way to run a code without compiling it to a .class file.

Comment: @algorian "But in Java, there is no way to run a code without compiling it to a .class file." - and what's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I don't want a .class file. I need to create a "java.lang.Class" object (the Class class of reflection). Compiling a .java file within java doesn't do that, does it?

Comment: @NiceBooks If the only input to what you're trying to do is a generated `.java` file, you'll have to compile it first, then load the resulting classfile into a `Class`. The compilation is a necessary intermediate step.

Comment: @NiceBooks compiling a .java file not just allows to obtain a `java.lang.Class` object, it's the only way to do it! The JVM needs the bytecode and the only way of obtaining bytecode is compiling, in fact, that's what "compiling" really means: generating bytecode that can be run by the JVM

Comment: @millimoose Ok now I get it. But how do I get a ClassLoader object from the .class file

Comment: maybe you wanted something much simpler - see latest update (after the horizontal bar)

Comment: Does Class.forName() compile the given class? (The same thing the API compiler does?) : `Class cls = Class.forName("com.example.ClassName"); Object obj = cls.newInstance();`   And could the generated object by `Class.forName()` be uesed to utilize a .java class file to make objects in the run time?

Answer (score 1):

If you do know the full class String name, why don't you use the Class.forName(className) method to obtain the class Object?
For example, if the class name is `yakam.yale.MyClass`, just call the

```
Class.forName("yakam.yale.MyClass");
```

and the game is played!

Comment: I assume with just having a `.java` file generated at runtime (what the OP stated), You can't use `Class.forName()` as there is no `.class` file and needs to be compiled first to have the `.class` file, using Compiler API